# How do I implement a multidimensional array where the the 1st dimension changes size as more 2nd dimension arrays are added?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, multidimensional-array

I have to produce a program which reads line-by-line an input document in the form:

`FootballTeamName1 : FootballTeamName2 : FootballTeam1Score : FootballTeam2Score`

From here I need to collect statistics (Goal difference / wins / losses) for each individual team across a full-season input file.

Is there a way to dynamically size an array to hold multiple set-size arrays of the form:

`{Teamname , integer, integer, integer}`

And once this has been implemented, how can I check that I am not adding arrays with the same teamname as that might already exist in the list?

Comment: Please create an model (Object, POJO, DTO, etc...) for your data and store these in a List.

Comment: Could I create Team objects using:
`public class Team{
   String teamname;
   int wins;
   int losses;
   int draws;
}`


Then create a list to store team objects with:
`ArrayList<Team> AllTeams = new Arraylist<Team>();`

Then create instances with:
`Allteams.add(new team('Teamname',0,0,0));`

Comment: Well, instead of a list, you could create a `Map` and map the `teamname` (if it is unique) to the relevant `Team` object.

Comment: How could I create the Team objects on-the-fly without duplicates??

Comment: I'm sorry to seem so slow, I have never encountered this area of Java before (I'm relatively new to it). Am I right in thinking that I can instantiate a team object using:

`MapName.put(Teamname, new Team(0,0,0));'

And if I do instantiate the team like this, how do I individually retrieve or alter the 3 integer values held within, 
do I use: `(MapName.get(teamname)).wins` or something similar?
Thank you for all your help so far, sorry if I am asking too many questions, I just find it very difficult.

Comment: See my response below.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to dynamically size an array to hold multiple set-size arrays of the form ...

Nope.  The size of a Java array is fixed when you allocate it (with `new`).  You cannot alter it, either to make it larger or smaller.

Here are your main alternatives:

- If you want your array to have a different size, then you need to allocate a *new* array, and copy the values from the old one to the new one ... as required.  Then update references to the old array with the new array reference.
- A better approach would be to use a `List` rather than an array.  You can increase and decrease the size of an `List` instance, and do a number of other useful things besides.
- In this case, it seems like a `Map<String, int[]>` or `Map<String, List<Integer>>` would be a better alternative to an `int[][]`.  (The `String` key is the team name.)

  A number of possible map classes that would work here.  For example:

  - A `HashMap` would give you fastest lookup.
  - A `LinkedHashmap` would preserve the order of the teams as you encountered them in your input.
  - A `TreeMap` would order the teams based on some ordering of the team names.

Comment: Would a `TreeMap` better facilitate sorting of the teams by one of the values? E.g Games played

Comment: Possibly.  But if you did that a `TreeSet` would be more appropriate.  Note that you only get to order the tree map / set by *one* criterion, and the data structure is going to **break** if you updated the entries in a way that alters the ordering; e.g. by adding a new result for a team while the team's record is in the set / map.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays don't change size dynamically. But you can learn from how dynamic collections uses arrays underneath and still grows with the need. If you deep dive into such collection, the logic is pretty simple: when a need arises to grow, a new array is created with bigger size, and the old array is copied into it.

You can use the same logic, can define your own decision, when to grow your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have dynamically sized Arrays since they don't change sizes. But these types of problems can be easily solved using HashMaps or ArrayLists.

If I am using HashMap, I can have something like `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>`, where `String` key is the Team Name and the `ArrayList<Integer>` will have Goal difference, wins and losses.

Using the HashMap has another advantage that since the keys have to be unique, you can't have the same Team Name twice.

Comment: This made a lot of sense to me, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Java is an Object Oriented Programming (OOP) Language. Multi-dimensional arrays are too messy. An `Map` or `List` of objects is the more practical (and dynamic) solution.

Below you will find three classes: `Team`, `TeamRegistry`, and `TeamTest`. The `Team` class is a POJO that has four fields: `name`, `wins`, `losses`, and `draws`. The `TeamRegistry` has a `Map<String,Team>` instance variable which stores `Team` and references them by their `name`. It handles retrieval and update methods to alter the values of each `Team`. The "`add()`" functions enable you to alter the existing values for a `Team`. Entering a positive value increases the current value and a negative value decreases it. These are primarily for syntactic sugar.

As you read in the values from the text file, you can simply call:

> **`TeamRegistry`**`.add(`**`teamName`**`,`**`wins`**`,`**`losses`**`,`**`draws`**`);`

### Team

```
package q27736168;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Team implements Comparable<Team>, Comparator<Team> {
    private String name;
    private int wins;
    private int losses;
    private int draws;

    public Team() {
        this("Team" + UUID.randomUUID(), 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public Team(String name) {
        this(name, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public Team(String name, int wins, int losses, int draws) {
        this.name = name;
        this.wins = wins;
        this.losses = losses;
        this.draws = draws;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getWins() {
        return wins;
    }

    public void setWins(int wins) {
        this.wins = wins;
    }

    public int getLosses() {
        return losses;
    }

    public void setLosses(int losses) {
        this.losses = losses;
    }

    public int getDraws() {
        return draws;
    }

    public void setDraws(int draws) {
        this.draws = draws;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Team other) {
        return name.compareTo(other.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Team team1, Team team2) {
        if (team2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (team1 == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        return team1.compareTo(team2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Team [name=" + name + ", wins=" + wins + ", losses="
                + losses + ", draws=" + draws + "]";
    }
}
```

### TeamRegistry

```
package q27736168;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TeamRegistry {
    private Map<String, Team> teams;
    private static final Map<String, Comparator<Team>> SORTERS;

    public static final String SORT_BY_WINS = "wins";
    public static final String SORT_BY_LOSSES = "losses";
    public static final String SORT_BY_DRAWS = "draws";

    static {
        SORTERS = new HashMap<String, Comparator<Team>>();
        SORTERS.put(SORT_BY_WINS, new Comparator<Team>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Team t1, Team t2) {
                if (t2 == null) return -1;
                if (t1 == null) return 1;
                int diff = -Integer.compare(t1.getWins(), t2.getWins());
                return diff == 0 ? t1.compareTo(t2) : diff;
            }
        });
        SORTERS.put(SORT_BY_LOSSES, new Comparator<Team>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Team t1, Team t2) {
                if (t2 == null) return -1;
                if (t1 == null) return 1;
                int diff = -Integer.compare(t1.getLosses(), t2.getLosses());
                return diff == 0 ? t1.compareTo(t2) : diff;
            }
        });
        SORTERS.put(SORT_BY_DRAWS, new Comparator<Team>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Team t1, Team t2) {
                if (t2 == null) return -1;
                if (t1 == null) return 1;
                int diff = -Integer.compare(t1.getDraws(), t2.getDraws());
                return diff == 0 ? t1.compareTo(t2) : diff;
            }
        });
    }

    public TeamRegistry() {
        teams = new HashMap<String, Team>();
    }

    public Team getTeam(String name) {
        Team team = teams.get(name);

        if (team == null) {
            return new Team(name);
        }

        return team;
    }

    public boolean teamExists(String name) {
        return teams.containsKey(name);
    }

    public void addWins(String name, int wins) {
        Team team = getTeam(name);
        addWins(team, wins);
        saveTeam(team);
    }

    public void addLosses(String name, int losses) {
        Team team = getTeam(name);
        addLosses(team, losses);
        saveTeam(team);
    }

    public void addDraws(String name, int draws) {
        Team team = getTeam(name);
        addDraws(team, draws);
        saveTeam(team);
    }

    public void add(String name, int wins, int losses, int draws) {
        Team team = getTeam(name);
        addWins(team, wins);
        addLosses(team, losses);
        addDraws(team, draws);
        saveTeam(team);
    }

    public List<Team> retrieveAll() {
        List<Team> list = getTeamsAsList();
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }

    public List<Team> retrieveAll(String sortBy) {
        List<Team> list = getTeamsAsList();
        Comparator<Team> comparator = SORTERS.get(sortBy);

        if (comparator == null) {
            return retrieveAll();
        }
        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
        return list;
    }

    protected void saveTeam(Team team) {
        teams.put(team.getName(), team);
    }

    protected void addWins(Team team, int wins) {
        team.setWins(team.getWins() + wins);
    }

    protected void addLosses(Team team, int losses) {
        team.setLosses(team.getLosses() + losses);
    }

    protected void addDraws(Team team, int draws) {
        team.setDraws(team.getDraws() + draws);
    }

    protected List<Team> getTeamsAsList() {
        return new ArrayList<Team>(teams.values());
    }
}
```

### TeamTest

```
package q27736168;

public class TeamTest {
    private TeamRegistry registry;

    public TeamRegistry getRegistry() {
        return registry;
    }

    public void setRegistry(TeamRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;
    }

    public TeamTest() {
        setRegistry(new TeamRegistry());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TeamTest t = new TeamTest();

        String[] teamNames = { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" };

        t.getRegistry().add(teamNames[0], 0, 0, 0);
        t.getRegistry().add(teamNames[0], 4, 0, 5);
        t.getRegistry().addLosses(teamNames[0], 3);

        t.getRegistry().add(teamNames[1], 0, 0, 0);
        t.getRegistry().add(teamNames[1], 1, 4, 3);
        t.getRegistry().addWins(teamNames[1], 4);

        t.getRegistry().add(teamNames[2], 0, 0, 0);
        t.getRegistry().add(teamNames[2], 3, 1, 3);
        t.getRegistry().addDraws(teamNames[2], 0);

        System.out.println("-- Sorted by `teamNames` array --");
        for (String teamName : teamNames) {
            System.out.println(t.getRegistry().getTeam(teamName));
        }
        System.out.println("\n-- Sorted by name (default) --");
        for (Team team : t.getRegistry().retrieveAll()) {
            System.out.println(team);
        }
        System.out.println("\n-- Sorted by wins --");
        for (Team team : t.getRegistry().retrieveAll(TeamRegistry.SORT_BY_WINS)) {
            System.out.println(team);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example Output from TeamTest

```
-- Sorted by `teamNames` array --
Team [name=Foo, wins=4, losses=3, draws=5]
Team [name=Bar, wins=5, losses=4, draws=3]
Team [name=Baz, wins=3, losses=1, draws=3]

-- Sorted by name (default) --
Team [name=Bar, wins=5, losses=4, draws=3]
Team [name=Baz, wins=3, losses=1, draws=3]
Team [name=Foo, wins=4, losses=3, draws=5]

-- Sorted by wins --
Team [name=Bar, wins=5, losses=4, draws=3]
Team [name=Foo, wins=4, losses=3, draws=5]
Team [name=Baz, wins=3, losses=1, draws=3]
```

Comment: Seriously dude, do you HAVE to do this guy's programming for him?  I don't think he even wants that.  And it is no help to anyone else.  (Except maybe other students in the same class as him who want to cheat on their homework.)

Comment: I don't want it done for me Stephen, I won't be using any of this until I've had the time to sit down, understand it, break apart the elements I haven't yet encountered, and then to add those elements of coding to my programming journal, I'll write something similar, yes, but this is only a small part of a much larger program, I'm going to need to understand it fully to be able to adapt it or its derivatives to fit into my existing code.

Comment: @SamHoole - That's what I thought :-).  The problem is that Mr Polywhirl has a habit of doing this.